# Dockerfile cannot run apt-get (exit code: 100)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, yocto, apt-get

I'm working with yocto and I'm trying to build my custom image using this a base: [yocto-ubuntu-20.04](https://hub.docker.com/layers/reliableembeddedsystems/yocto/ubuntu-20.04-base/images/sha256-afdabf6b5b951ffbd54523cf358d49dfe32550058cf35e112c0ea51ce94ab095).

I have this simple docker file:

```
FROM reliableembeddedsystems/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base
RUN apt-get update
```

But I'm getting permissions error when building:

```
user@user$ sudo docker build .
[...]
------                                                                                                               
 > [2/2] RUN apt-get update:
0.214 Reading package lists...
0.753 E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
0.753 E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM reliableembeddedsystems/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base
   2 | >>> RUN apt-get update
   3 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

If I add `sudo` to `RUN apt-get update` line I get a different error asking for password:

```
 > [2/2] RUN sudo apt-get update:                                                                                    
0.207 sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM reliableembeddedsystems/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base
   2 | >>> RUN sudo apt-get update
   3 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Which is the correct way to work with it?

Another question: if run a container using the base image, I notice that I can use sudo. But, how am I supposed to know the password? Is it okay to use `sudo` in here?

Comment: This question is specific to the base image you are using. If you used the regular `FROM ubuntu:20.04` this would work. I suspect the base image is setting a `USER` at the end that isn't root. You can try putting `USER root` before the RUN line.

Comment: Well, adding `USER root` seems to work! And also solves my second question about how to use `sudo` inside the container (now it doesn't ask about a pass). I'm not sure if this is the correct way to work with it. Anyway it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the base image sets a user other than root. This can be fixed using:

```
FROM reliableembeddedsystems/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base
USER root
RUN apt-get update
```